# Re-prioritize items in a rabbitMq priority queue

Tags: c#, queue, rabbitmq

Is there a way to re prioritize items that are already in a RabbitMQ priority queue? Some messages cannot be processed immediately therefore my program responds with a  BasicNack and the message is re-queued. However the re-queued message is retrieved next time the Dequeue command is called. Is there a way to re-prioritize the item to the bottom before/after I call the Nack, so that I could continue with other requests until my program is ready to process that request?

Comment: I think it'd be possible doing some fancy work with dead letter exchanges and shovels. Otherwise you'd have to do it manually

Comment: That is exactly what I did, was actually pretty simple. Thanks